# Redirecting back to Portlet from ResourceMapping in Spring 3 portlets

Tags: spring, spring-3, jsr286, spring-portlet-mvc, vignette

I am trying to work out a way to provide a CSV download through a Spring 3 Portlet.  I have a method that uses the `@ResourceMapping` annotation to define a handler that takes some report params in the form of a `@ModelAttribute`, builds the report, and returns it.  The catch-22 I am running into is validating the parameters being send in from the client form.

If I make the handler a `@ResourceMapping`, I can set the headers and write out the report as using the `ResourceResponse`, but I can't seem to figure out how to redirect the user back to the Portlet view with errors when their input fails validation.  However, if I make it an `@ActionMapping`, I can then check the `BindingResult`s and forward them back to the form as needed, but the `ActionResponse` doesn't allow me to set the Content-Disposition header nor write out the CSV bytes, which is sort of critical for sending the report back.

I am at a total loss here, as I don't even know what my options are.  Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do with a Portlet?  Are there other examples I could look at for a possible work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use both `@ActionMapping` and `@ResourceMapping` to fulfill your requirement.

As you said you were able to handle the `validation` errors using the `@ActionResponse`, I'll tell you how to handle the `Resource Streaming`.

As you know every `@ActionResponse` is followed by a `@RenderResponse`, just return the same view but, with  a hidden `iframe` this time whose `src` points to the `ResourceURL`.

Now the `Request` you receive in `@ResourceMapping` is something which is already `Validated`. So, you can now serve your `CSV`.

I dont know how complex is your `UI` and if you are using `jsp` as `views` in your application. If nicely managed, `Validation` can be handled by `@ResourceMapping`.

Thank you

Comment: I am giving you the nod as this is a good solution.  However, I chose a different route of using an AJAX call to validate, then upon validation of the input make another AJAX call to get the CSV.  But, the iframe was an idea I didn't think of.